# How can I add a key binding for a quickMenu similar to the "Refactor" context menu in JDT?

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-jdt

I want to add a shortcut to my eclipse plugin to show a quick menu with existing bindings. It should work like the "Refactor" quick menu in JDT.

**Shortcut for quick menu in JDT:**
[image: Shortcut for "Refactor" quick menu]

**JDT quick menu:**

[image: JDT quickMenu]

I already added a binding and a command but it seems there is something missing. The *Delete Something* entry is also working for the context menu, just the shortcut to the quick menu is missing.
Does anybody how to do this?

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.bindings">
  <key
        commandId="myplugin.refactoring.actions.DeleteSomething"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+5">
  </key>
  <key
        commandId="myplugin.refactoring.quickMenu"
        schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
        sequence="M1+9">
  </key>
```

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
  <command
        categoryId="myplugin.category.refactor"
        description="Delete Something"
        id="myplugin.refactoring.actions.DeleteSomething"
        name="Extract Method">
  </command>
  <command
        categoryId="myplugin.category.refactor"
        id="myplugin.refactoring.quickMenu"
        name="Show Refactor Quick Menu">
  </command>
  <category
        id="myplugin.category.refactor"
        name="Refactor">
  </category>
```

Comment: are you using e4 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it like this:

Add a command for the quick menu and set a default handler.

```
      <command
        defaultHandler="myplugin.refactoring.QuickmenuHandler"
        id="myplugin.refactoring.quickMenu"
        name="Show Refactor Quick Menu">
      </command>
```

The handler should be able to create the menu. Something like this:

```
@Override
public Object execute(ExecutionEvent event) throws ExecutionException {
    ...
    Menu menu = new Menu(some parent);
    new MenuItem(menu, SWT.PUSH).setText("...");
    menu.setVisible(true);
    return null;
}
```

Add a shortcut to the command (as you did):

```
 <key
    commandId="myplugin.refactoring.quickMenu"
    schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"
    sequence="M1+9">
 </key>
```

Finally bind all of this together in the menu extension point:

```
   <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
        allPopups="false"
        locationURI="popup:ch.arenae.dnp.frame.popup?after=additions">
     <menu
           commandId="myplugin.refactoring.quickMenu"
           label="Refactor">
        <command
              commandId="<first refactoring command>"
              style="push">
        </command>
     </menu>
     ...
  </menuContribution>
```

The important point is the commandId attribute in the menu element. It is used to display the keyboard shortcut in the menu.

Comment: Peter, i have implemented a minimal example. While the context menu appears and the shortcut also works to display the quick menu, the shortcut key binding is not displayed in the context menu. Thus, a user has to know the shortcut. Is there some extra step to get the shortcut to be displayed in the context menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at how JDT implements the same. For instance, when looking at the Eclipse 3.8.2 source code, you'll see interesting method:

```
org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.RefactorActionGroup.installQuickAccessAction()
```

which is called when Java editor is opened. This is were [programmatic handler association](http://tldr.es/31z) with current editor takes place.

To summarize how it's done in JDT:

1. First, they have a command declaration in plugin.xml:

   <command
       name="%ActionDefinition.refactorQuickMenu.name"
       description="%ActionDefinition.refactorQuickMenu.description"
       categoryId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.category.refactoring"
       id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.refactor.quickMenu">
2. They declare a key binding:

   <key
       sequence="M2+M3+T"
       commandId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.refactor.quickMenu"
       schemeId="org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration"/>
3. They associate this command with a handler once editor is created. The handler itself (`org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.actions.JDTQuickMenuCreator`) takes care of filling the quick menu with items.

You don't have to associate a command with a handler programmatically - another option is using [org.eclipse.ui.handlers](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fworkbench_cmd_handlers.htm) extension point.